Difficult power limit $\lim_{x \to \infty} x^{\left ( -\frac{1}{x} \right )}$
This is my work so far
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} x^{\left ( -\frac{1}{x} \right )}=
\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{1}{x^\left({\frac{1}{x}} \right)}=\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{1}{e^{\ln x^\left({\frac{1}{x}}\right)}}=\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{1}{e^{\frac{\ln x}{x}}}$$
Now what's the next step?
I'm stuck and I don't know what to do! I need to solve this without differentiation! Can someone help me?

$\ln x /x \to 0$ as $ x \to \infty$.

@geetha290krm But isn't lnx/x intederminate form?

$\ln(\infty)/\infty$ may not be meaningful, but the limit is.  For example $\ln(10000)/10000 < 0.001$

It is a standard fact - sometimes referred to as something like ‘powers beat logs’ so you might Google things like that to get more info or look in an introductory real analysis book

In my first mathematical analysis course we proved a theorem called the "hierarchy of infinities". Look for something about it.

Let $x=e^y$ with $y\to infty$ then $\log x /x=y/e^y$.

@user  and after that? what do you do after $$\frac{y}{e^{y}}$$?

We can use that $e^y>y^2$ or by definition or proving it by induction.

@user And who îs $y^2$? Another function?

Since $e^y>y^2$ then $y/e^y<y/y^2=1/y\to 0$

If you let $x=\frac 1 y$, $\lim_{x \to \infty} x^{\left ( -\frac{1}{x} \right )}=\lim_{y \to 0 } y^y$

The proof can be performed without knowledge of the $\log$ function.
Let $2\le n\le x\le n+1.$ Then $$1\le x^{1/x} \le (n+1)^{1/n}\le (2n)^{1/n}=:1+y_n$$ Hence by the binomial formula we obtain $$2n=(1+y_n)^{n}\ge {n\choose 2}y_n^2$$ which gives $$y_n^2\le {4\over n-1}\le {4\over x-2 }$$ Summarizing we get for $x\ge 2$ $$1 \le x^{1/x}\le 1+{2\over \sqrt{x-2}}$$ Therefore the limit is equal $1.$

https://imgur.com/a/nZwPFCj    Where did these inequalities come from?Can you explain?

If $1\le a\le b$ and $0<c\le d$ then $a^c\le b^d.$

Your work is fine and, as noticed in the comments, you reduce all to the well known limit
$$\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{\ln x}{x}=0$$
which can be proved without l'Hospital's rule in many different ways as already shown for example here

Evaluation of $ \lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\frac{\ln (x)}{x}$ using Squeeze theorem
Find $\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{\ln x}{x}=0$ without l'Hopital's rule
Proof that limit $\frac{\ln(x)}x$ for $x\to\infty$ is $0$.


in the second link where does $$\frac{\sqrt(x)}{x}$$ and 0 come from?

We are using that $\log x < \sqrt x$.
